# Serial execution of an ansible playbook to upgrade to the latest model of an azure vmss

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-vm-scale-set

I have ansible tooling to generate images in azure, and terraform tooling to apply the images to the vmsses I have in azure. However azure only marks the vmss instances with the lates_model boolean flag, thus I need to open each instance in the vmss and hit the upgrade button, that restarts the machine.

I saw several modules to manage vmsses, however my I need to upgrade(reboot) the instances using the serial parameter in my playbook. That is the problem I can go [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks/blob/master/vmss_images/04-update-vmss-image.yml) way. In general getting the inventory in the module is not the best idea I guess, as Ansible does not know that list is in fact an inventory. I need an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the configuration of the VMSS and I see you set the upgrade policy with the `manual`. And in this situation, you need to upgrade all the instances yourself by selecting.

In ansible, you only can use the module `azure_rm_virtualmachinescaleset` to update the VMSS, the other module just get the facts of the VMSS. If you want to update the configuration and then all the instances upgrade automatically, you need to set the `upgrade_policy` with `Automatic`.

Comment: using upgrade_mode in terraform helps, however there is another question, before rebooting the instance(upgrade requires that), I need to perform some in OS tasks, stop a process for example. How can I do that with terraform?

Comment: @EdikMkoyan If it's helpful to you please accept it. And you'd better ask another question for another issue with more details. But a piece of advice here for it is using the cloud-init, it may help.

Comment: the correct answer is upgrade_mode not upgrade_policy. Please correct so I'll be able to accept your answer as a correct one.

Comment: @EdikMkoyan Where do you find the upgrade_mode? I only see the upgrade policy in ansible.

Comment: I guess we are talking about two different ways of doing the same thing. In terraform it is upgrade_mode, by default it is set to manual, and that is the reason why I am doing the upgrades from the portal.azure.com. The only reason Ansible should be used here, is custom, in OS steps before rebooting the machine. Terraform's termination provisioners(ansible?) maybe also can be used, but that is a bad idea, I guess.

Comment: @EdikMkoyan You add the ansible tag, so I give the solution in ansible. And in terraform, it should be [`upgrade_policy_mode`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_scale_set#upgrade_policy_mode). I think I did not give the wrong one.